# Basics of using MongoDB on remote server with SSH

Tags: mongodb, ssh, vps

I'm having trouble getting started with MongoDB via SSH on a VPS.  Note that MongoDB was installed by admins with the VPS service, not me.  I have to presume they installed it correctly.  Unfortunately, they provide zero support documentation and I can't figure it out after reading countless official MongoDB docs and even more found elsewhere.

I am able to SSH into the remote server just fine.  I can check the MongoDB version, and mongosh is there, too.  But I cannot figure out how to get to the point where I can create a new collection, or even start MongoDB, if that's what I need to do.

Here are some of the things I've tried in the shell for the VPS.  The closest I've gotten is by running `mongosh -nodb` which seems to get me inside of MongoDB, but I know that option means "no database," so it's not what I need to do.

```
$ ssh customusername@207.196.153.34
Last login: Thu Dec 29 11:56:53 2022 from 82.204.238.49
customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongod -version
db version v6.0.3
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "rhel70",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongosh --version
1.6.1
customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongosh -nodb
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63abf66ca872ab436a8040c8
Using Mongosh:      1.6.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

> use test-db
MongoshInvalidInputError: [SHAPI-10004] No connected database
> exit
customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongosh --username customusername 
Enter password: ********************************
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63abf8c15a47f0e078be3d76
Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
customusername@customdomain.com [~]#
```

I am able to pull up "help" files.  And I've tried multiple variations of `# mongod mongodb://customusername@127.0.0.1:27017/` which fail.

```
customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongod help

customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongosh -h

customusername@customdomain.com [~]# mongod mongodb://customusername@127.0.0.1:27017/
```

That last command returns a few lines which indicate it might be working, then it fails with message: "Invalid command: mongodb://customusername@127.0.0.1:27017/" And then it displays a number of "General options" such as "-h [ --help ]".  I can't make sense of most of them.

Note that I cannot install MongoDB/mongosh locally because my machine is too old, so I have to be able to log in through SSH and handle it that way.  If I can figure it out via SSH, maybe I'll try something like MongoDB Compass next, which I am able to install locally.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

---

**UPDATE:** I think I've made progress, but am still not there yet.

I think I got MongoDB running with this, after creating a directory called "mongodb" to hold data files:

`# mongod --port 28015 --dbpath ./mongodb/`

A string of messages come up in my terminal, with the last being related to listening ("ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections"), and the process appears to continue running.

I then open a new terminal window, SSH in, and run this:

`# mongosh --port 28015`

Which appears to land me in a mongo shell in which I'm able to create a new collection:

```
test> use test-db
switched to db test-db
test-db>
```

Also, I notice that the original terminal window with the open process outputs connection-related messages as I interact with the second window (e.g. "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted").

I looked inside of the `/mongodb/` directory and there are a number of mongo-related files in there now, "collection-0-5001736531146682033.wt", "index-1-5001736531146682033.wt", "storage.bson", and so forth.  So, I think the db creation is working.

---

**UPDATE TWO**

Was struggling with why the `show` command was throwing an error, since `use` was already working, then figured out I needed to insert a document first:

`test> db.tours.insertOne({name: "Some Name", price: 19, rating: 3.5})`

The full command is `show dbs` and then the "test" database appears.

Comment: This is a really broad question.  You might start with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes, and then ask more specific question if you get into trouble.

Comment: `--nodb` means "no database", i.e. you just open the mongo shell but you don't connect to any database.

Comment: First of all, you need to start the `mongod` database service (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/). Once the service is up an running, you can use the `mongosh` to connect to the database.

Comment: It is all correct what you have done. You started the database and you connected your shell to it. Now, what do you like to do? There is nothing you stated in your question.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm getting there.  Thanks.  But why is the `show` command throwing an error?  Once I feel like `use` and `show` are working, I'll move on to more regular mongo tasks like manipulating data, or accessing it via Compass.  So, I guess this is resolved if I can get `show` to work properly.

Comment: Ah, I just needed to insert a document (`db.tours.insertOne({...})` before `show` worked, and the actual command is `show dbs`.  So, it's working and I'm good to go I think with very basic SSH mongodb.  Thanks for checking this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can check out my two updates above.  I was able to access and do very basic operations with MongoDB on a VPS with SSH.

Also, here are some helpful links, if you struggle with similar issues.

**Mongo Shell basics:**
https://www.mongodb.com/basics/get-started#get-started-with-mongodb
(skip down to the "Get Started with MongoDB" subsection, since the top of the page is about the Atlas interface)

**Setting up admin and user accounts via command line:**
https://medium.com/@haxzie/getting-started-with-mongodb-setting-up-admin-and-user-accounts-4fdd33687741

Good luck!